# adding a tick mark for selected item for popup menu in android

Tags: android, popupmenu

I created popup menu for a Image button and applied some styles to it.

How to reduce popup menu width and add a tick mark when the user selects the popup menu item ?

My Code :

```
btn_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu a_popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), a_period);
            a_popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_a, a_popup.getMenu());

            a_popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Clicked "+item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            a_popup.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

To Add tick mark when popmenu is selected,

Your menu file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/flat"
              android:checkable="true"
              android:title="Flat" />
        <item android:id="@+id/stadium"
            android:checkable="true"    
              android:title="Stadium" />
        <item android:id="@+id/jazz"
        android:checkable="true"
              android:title="Jazz" />
         <item android:id="@+id/rock"
         android:checkable="true"
              android:title="Rock" />
         <item android:id="@+id/pop"
         android:checkable="true"
              android:title="Pop" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

in setOnMenuItemClickListener() write below code:

popup.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);

It will select **3rd item**.

To reduce **width** of popup menu, you can use **Popup Window**. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21469792/how-can-i-change-popup-item-width-size)

Comment: for this `getItem(SELECTED MENU ITEM INDEX)` please give me a example by looking my above code.

Comment: Is it possible to move the tick mark to left of the text.(default is right to text.)

Comment: if you want tick mark to left then use popup window instead of default popup menu.

Comment: please can you explain

Comment: you can create custom layout file and inflate it on popup window, I have already mentioned link in my ans on how to use popup window